# i have a button on click -1 in database in Every time i want on click second +1

Tags: php, html

i have a button on click -1 in database in Every time i want on click second +1 , third -1 And so on

code html & php

```
<form action="ind.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="click" value="click" id="click">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['click'])){
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=testt;",$username,$password);
    $update = $database->prepare("UPDATE test SET NUMBER=NUMBER-1 WHERE ID = 1");
    $update->execute();
}
if(isset($_POST['click'])){
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=testt;",$username,$password);
    $update = $database->prepare("UPDATE test SET NUMBER=NUMBER+1 WHERE ID = 1");
    $update->execute();}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need more logic in your code.

Check what current value is, then use +1 or -1 based on current value.

if ($click === 1) { // - 1 } else { // + 1 }